# What, if any, is the term for a node whose children are all leaf nodes?

Tags: data-structures, terminology, trees

More specifically, I'm interested to know if there is a term that describes a tree node that meets two conditions:
- It has >= one child
- Any children that it has are all leaf nodes.

Comment: Maybe penultimate node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are classified as nodes of height 1 by convention in the case of a rooted tree.

The height of a node $N$ is the number of edges on the longest downward simple path from $N$ to a leaf, according to *Introduction to Algorithms* by CLRS as well as [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree).

You might want to use penultimate nodes as suggested by Orlp. Please note some papers define a penultimate node slight differently on general graphs as a nonleaf node that is adjacent to a leaf node. For example, [Patrolling Games](http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/opre.1110.0983).